# Pre Onboarding, if data is going to be required, should we get some or all of it up front during account creation?

Tags: onboarding, required-fields

I'm working on a fundraising app where the client wants the user to start creating the fundraiser details before creating the account. These data points setup the data to display.

They are gathering things like org name, type, group, and then some fundraiser details such as goals, causes. Then they ask for only the state location for pricing reasons. However, there are more required data points once they log in such as getting the rest of the address besides state.

I'm thinking if we need to get the whole address anyway. Do we need to be afraid of the friction during account creation?

Comment: If you need all that information, it is only fair to request it before creating an account. Or is there anything you can do without that information?

Answer (score 1):

Sometime back I worked on a nutrition app where there was a quick on boarding of 3 steps to capture basic data, age, weight, height and goal, with that the app was able to create a standard nutrition plan, then inside the app there were settings to complete the user profile with preferences, allergies, exercise routines etc..., the more complete that was the profile the better recommendations the app was able to made.

My recommendation in your case is keep the pre on boarding quick, but request the minimum you need to give back some value to the user; engage it, if the user is interested, it won't hurt to add extra information latter on for a more detailed information in exchange.

There is an article from Microsoft from 2015 where the say that the average attention humans keep is around 8s, so keep it short but valuable.

https://dl.motamem.org/microsoft-attention-spans-research-report.pdf